# Rails: select unique values from 2 models with belongs_to and has_many relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models: Player and Item

Player Model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end
```

Item Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :player
end
```

I'm trying to store an array of unique players (only their id and names) that created the 5 most recent items.

It works if I make a loop and do the query one by one

```
Item.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).first.player.id
Item.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).first.player.name
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to use pluck to do the query without a loop and also only take unique values of players?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get an array of unique players that created the 5 most recent items or do you want to get an array of the 5 most recent unique players that created an item?

The latter will always return 5 players (when you've got 5 or more players that have created items) where as the former might only return one single player (since he could have created the 5 most recent items).

If you want the players of the 5 most recent items, try this:

```
player_ids = Item.order(created_at :desc).limit(5).pluck(:player_id).uniq
Player.where(id: player_ids).pluck(:id, :name)
```

If you want the 5 most recent unique players that've created an item, try this:

```
player_ids = Item.order(created_at :desc).pluck(:player_id).uniq.first(5)
Player.where(id: player_ids).pluck(:id, :name)
```

You could even use a `join` with the `player` association. Note that you've got to use the table name in your `pluck` now:

```
Item.joins(:player).order(created_at :desc).limit(5).pluck('players.id', 'players.name').uniq
```

or

```
Item.joins(:player).order(created_at :desc).pluck('players.id', 'players.name').uniq.first(5)
```

Comment: What I wanted was the second one, which will always return 5 players. Works great, thanks!